# Showing download application on diawi.com for iOS using Ionic framework

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I am using the Ionic framework for my project. I am using diawi.com to install my application on an iOS device. I am using iOS version 16.1.1. When I open the link from diawi.com, it shows "Download application" and I can't install it (See picture “Office iPhone.jpeg”). But in other iOS versions, it shows "Install application" and I can install it (See photo “Personal Phone.jpeg”).

[image: Personal Phone.jpeg]
[image: Office iPhone.jpeg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had some problems using diawi too. Now I use [appho.st](https://appho.st/) normally.